# How do i pass props inside a Link tag?

Tags: reactjs

I got 2 components: First and Second

I would like to pass a prop "name" inside a First link tag to my Second component:

[First component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjfaj.png)

and call it in the Second:

[Second component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG6Wa.png)

Component 1:

```
return(
    <Container>
        <Title>Inserir</Title>            
       
        <Link to={{
            pathname:'/painel',
            nome: 'Rafael'
        }}>Ver</Link>            
    </Container>
);
```

Component 2:

```
return(
    <Container>
        <h1>Name here</h1>            
    </Container>
);
```

}

Comment: Can you please post the code as text?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as state

```
<Link to={{
            pathname:'/painel',
            state: {name: 'Rafael'}
        }}>Ver</Link>
```

Component 2

```
return(
    <Container>
        <h1>{props.location.state.name}</h1>            
    </Container>
);
```

Comment: Failed to compile

./src/pages/Visualizar/index.js
  Line 8:18:  'props' is not defined  no-undef